# Why is my compiler skipping function call?

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node*next;
};
struct node*start;
void create(struct node*ptr)
{
    char ch;
    do
    {
     printf("Enter the data of node\n");
     scanf("%d",&ptr->data);
     fflush(stdin);
     printf("Do you wish to continue?(y/n)\n");
     ch=getchar();
     if(ch=='y')
     {
         ptr=ptr->next;
     }
     else
        ptr->next=NULL;
    }while(ch=='y');
}
void insert(struct node*ptr)
{
    struct node*p;
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the value of data for node1\n");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);
    fflush(stdin);
    p->next=ptr;
    ptr=p;
}
void display(struct node*ptr)
{
    printf("Your Linked list is\n");
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    printf("Hello and welcome to Linked List program\n");
    start=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    create(start);
    display(start);
    printf("Let us now add a node to your linked list\n");
    insert(start);
    display(start);
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is skipping function call insert and display. I've checked logic for all the functions they seems right to me. Moreover display and create before printf are working.
The functions after print statement (i.e. insert and display function) are not working.

Comment: `fflush()` should not be called with `stdin` as the parameter. So the first thing to do is refactor the code so that you can remove all of the `fflush(stdin)` calls.

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code. It will show you what happens.

Comment: malloc.h is obsolete since forever. Use stdlib.h instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `create` can invoke undefined behavior if you will try to append one more node because in this case after this statement

```
ptr=ptr->next;
```

the pointer `ptr` has indeterminate value.

At least you should write

```
 if(ch=='y')
 {
     ptr->next = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
     ptr = ptr->next;
 }
```

Though you also need to check that the memory allocation was successful.

The function `insert`  does not change the original pointer `start` in this statement

```
ptr=p;
```

because the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer `start`. Instead it changes the local variable `ptr`.

The function should be written at least like

```
struct node * insert(struct node*ptr)
{
    struct node*p;
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Enter the value of data for node1\n");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);
    fflush(stdin);
    p->next=ptr;
    return p;
}
```

and called like

```
start = insert( start );
```

Though again the function does not check whether the memory was allocated successfully.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to declare the pointer `start` as a global variable.

And for example memory allocation for the first node should not be done in main. It should be done in a function.

Functions should do one thing for example to allocate a node and insert it in the list. Any prompts that ask the user to enter a value should be done either in main or in another function.

Answer (score 1):

Many problems.....

In `create`, you pass a pointer that is not properly initialized. So `ptr= ptr->next` makes `ptr` an invalid value. In `main` you should have `start->ptr= 0;`

What is the use of having a loop in `create` when you pass only one element and do not allocate new elements in`create`?

Because of the first observation, `display` will try to fetch an invalid `ptr->data` and probably aborts the program.

In `insert`, `ptr=p;` will not pass the changed `ptr` to the caller because a parameter is a local copy (call by value). You must either pass a double pointer, or make it the return value.

As said, use a debugger to find out more about what is going on.